# matlab javaclasspath() not working in mac

Tags: java, matlab, osx-snow-leopard, pwd

Here is the matlab code:

```
javaclasspath(pwd); % set java path to current working directory

% call the java function
Result = googleTrend.TrendDataExtractor.ExtractData(Email, Password, word, from, till, scale, handlerHttps, handlerHttp);
```

It runs fine in windows but in mac it gives the following error:

```
Undefined variable "googleTrend" or class "googleTrend.TrendDataExtractor.ExtractData"
```

I think javaclasspath(pwd) is not working correct.
Note: pwd returns the current working directory

Comment: is googleTrend a subdirectory of the current path? Or is googleTrend in a Jar file?

Comment: To add to Memming's comment, we need to see location and contents (or portions) of the relevant *.jar and *.class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was problem with the pwd. I hard-coded the the path in javaclasspath it worked fine